# How to say 'I turned towards right to avoid the vehicle dash'

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm describing an accident that I averted in the past. Actually, a lady was driving towards me in speed. And to avoid the dash **I turned my bike towards right.** It wasn't like I took the right turn. But I did deviate from my route to avoid the accident. How should I rephrase it?

Comment: *I **swerved** right to avoid a collision*. For future questions, consider also our sister site dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language (as opposed to *this* site, which is much more abstruse, academic, and technical): [ELL.se].

Comment: If you think it's important to preclude (or at least, *discourage*) the "took the right turn" interpretation, but you don't want anything as dramatic as *swerved, veered*, you could say *I turned **to the** right.* It's not idiomatic to *turn towards/toward right* - but usually you just *turn right* anyway.

Comment: you could say you veered right

Comment: I agree with "veered" or "swerved". but an aside: it appears you're using "dash" to mean collision or crash.  It isn't normally used to mean that.  The only "dash" associated with a vehicle is the dashboard, commonly referred to as the dash.  Otherwise, it means to move quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the verbs you seem to be looking for are "swerve", and "veer":

> I *swerved* my bicycle to the right to avoid the onrushing car, since the driver didn't see me.
>
> I *veered* to the right to avoid running into the car.

If on foot you can use "dodge"

> I quickly *dodged* to the right to avoid the car barreling toward me.

as well as various other fun expressions:

> I *jinked* to the right to avoid the oncoming vehicle.

A "jink" is a sharp turn to one side, and then another quick turn back to straight, like:

> ¯¯¯¯¯\_____

.

> I *skittered* to the right to avoid a collision.

If on foot, "skittering" is a series of short steps, like an insect.  You can also say "hopped" if you did it one quick movement.

> I quickly *sidestepped* to the right to avoid being run over.

A sidestep is pretty much as it sounds, a quick step to one side or the other.